# Can't Use UIButton.isHidden = false. How could I hide my button then?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.isHidden = false
    }
```

I am trying to hide the button right at the beginning then if a value is true, then I would show the button. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hiding use:

```
    button.alpha = 0
```

or

```
    button.isHidden = true
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it said that: Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'alpha'.

Comment: @ThomasTseng are you sure you have connected button from storyboard as outlet not an action?

Comment: Thank you Kamajabu! So could I connect the button as an outlet and an action?

Comment: Outlet connection is for presentation (like size, position, colors) and action is for... well, action ;) You can (and really should) read more about it here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html